# Upload files using EditForm in Blazor Server?

Tags: file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-editform

I am using Blazor Server-Side and want to upload some files. I don't need any progress bar or so and only want to upload the files when the `EditForm` is submitted. The popular solutions I found until now (Synfusion Blazor File Upload, [Steve Sandersons File Upload](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/)) upload files once a file is selected, not on the `EditForm`submit. Can't I just use `input type="file"` in HTML for my simple case? How exactly would I do that with an `EditForm` and how would I receive the file on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Steve Sandersons File Upload](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/09/13/blazor-inputfile/) works, in

```
void HandleFileSelected(IFileListEntry[] files)
{
    // Do something with the files, e.g., read them
}
```

simply store the `files` are and access `IFileListEntry.Data` when the form is submitted. No need to read the stream immediately in `HandleFileSelected`.

Comment: update for 2022 
use InputFileChangeEventArgs  instead of IFileListEntry[]

Answer (score -1):

Steve Sandersons File Upload is fine, but not necessary.  My own code handles the fileuploads in the `Change` event, but I'm pretty sure you can defer the upload with something like:

```
<InputFile OnChange="HandleFileUpload" multiple></InputFile>

@code {
    InputFileChangeEventArgs FileArgs {get; set;}

 async Task HandleFileUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    FileArgs = e;
}
```

Then whenever you're ready to actually process the files, go ahead and process the arguments with something like (for example, in your form submit method):

```
foreach (var imageFile in FileArgs.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
{
    // Do file stuff
}
```